# How to bind PDO values for queries involving MySQL Date and Time types

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, pdo

I have a db with two respective tables for DATES . . .

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
     `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `date` date NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and TIMES . . .

```
CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I'm trying to bind date and time values collected from HTML date/time input fields to queries that will check if the respective date/time already exists its table. If it doesn't, my code runs another query that inserts said date/time into the corresponding table.

```
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

$date = isset($data['date']) ? $data['date'] : NULL;
$time = isset($data['time']) ? $data['time'] : NULL;

If(isset($date)){
    $sqlDs = "SELECT * FROM `dates` WHERE date=:date";
    $stDs = $conn->prepare ( $sqlDs );
    $stDs->bindValue(':date', $date);
    $stDs->execute();
    $rDs = $stDs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    If(! $rDs ){
        $sqlDi = "INSERT INTO `dates` (date) VALUES (:date)";
        $stDi = $conn->prepare ( $sqlDi );
        $stDi->bindValue(':date', $date);
        If ($stDi->execute()){
            $dCode = $conn->lastInsertId();
            $msg['temp'] = 'success';
            $msg['body'] = $msg['body'].$date.' added to Dates.';
        }Else{
            $msg['temp'] = 'error';
            $body = isset($msg['body']) ? $msg['body'] : '';
            $msg['body'] = $body.'Date at '.$date.' didn`t work.';
        }
    }Else{
        $dCode = $rDs['did'];
        }
    }

    If(isset($time)){
        $sqlTs = "SELECT * FROM `times` WHERE time=:time";
        $stTs = $conn->prepare ( $sqlTs );
        $stTs->bindValue(':time', $time);
        $stTs->execute();
        $rTs = $stTs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        If(! $rTs ){
            $sqlTi = "INSERT INTO `times` (time) VALUES (:time)";
            $stTi = $conn->prepare ( $sqlTi );
            $stTi->bindValue(':time', $time);
            If ($stTi->execute()){
                $tCode = $conn->lastInsertId();
                $msg['temp'] = 'success';
                $msg['body'] = $msg['body'].$time.' added to Times.';
            }Else{
                $msg['temp'] = 'error';
                $body = isset($msg['body']) ? $msg['body'] : '';
                $msg['body'] = $body.'Time for '.$time.' didn`t work.';
            }
        }Else{
            $tCode = $rTs['tid'];
        }

    }
```

I can't seem to figure out the right way to bind these values with the correct format for MySQL. No strtotime() syntax or anything else I've come across so far has worked. Is there perhaps something else I'm missing? I know I should figure this out myself but I'm coming up on the end of this project and I'm just so tired of wrestling with it.

> UPDATE: I forgot to execute the SELECT queries. This code works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sqlDi = "INSERT INTO `dates`(:date)";
```

This isn't correct syntax for the INSERT statement.

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, ...) VALUES (value, ...)
```

MySQL supports an alternative (non-standard) syntax that I find a little easier:

```
INSERT INTO tablename SET col1 = value1, col2 = value2, ...
```

You can't use bind parameters for column names, only for values. `INSERT INTO dates (:date)` is incorrect for this reason, because the parenthesized list following the table name is for column names.

The other advice I would have is to check the return value of `prepare()` before you assume the query parsing was successful. If you had done this, you would have known you had a syntax error.

```
 $stDi = $conn->prepare ( $sqlDi );
 if ($stDi === false) {
     error_log(print_r($conn->errorInfo(), true));
     error_log("SQL = [$sqlDi]");
     die("A database error occurred, please report to the site administrator");
 }
```

Comment: I do not agree with the last post. While it doesn't hurt, it is unnecessary. PDO will throw an exception if there is an error and that if will never be reached.

Comment: By default, PDO doesn't throw exceptions on errors. You have to enable that deliberately. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php says: `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT - This is the default mode.`

Comment: Yes, but then the problem is the disabled error reporting, not the missing 4 lines of code after every method call.

Comment: I agree, I enable exceptions as my preferred way of using PDO. But not every PHP developer likes to use exceptions. The asker's code does not enable PDO exceptions.

Comment: Also enabling exceptions doesn't eliminate the need to write some code to `catch()` them. Users don't like it if you allow exceptions to just blow up your app.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I had made these changes earlier and it did, of course, make all the difference when querying directly through the DB but I'm still not successful with the PHP. I've tried logging the errors but either nothing is getting logged or I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: `error_log()` outputs to the http server's error log. I always keep a terminal window open with `tail -f error.log` when I'm developing PHP.

Comment: @BillKarwin the user interaction is irrelevant to database exceptions. It is implemented elsewhere and doesn't affect your database related code.